# Can't create Laravel 8 project, problem appeared after release of Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm having an issue creating a Laravel 8 project. Before the release of Laravel 9, it was working normally. However, if I create a project using `laravel new example-app`, it will create Laravel 9 projects. The following error appears when I use `composer create-project-prefer-dist laravel/laravel:8.16.1 blog`. What can I do to solve this problem? I currently use Laravel version 8.0. Note I can't upload images of the errors because of reputation.

> [InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package laravel/laravel with
> version 8.16.1.
>
> create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source]
> [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository
> REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository]
> [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts]
> [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs]
> [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ]
> [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [] []
> []

Comment: It's much better if you [don't upload images of code/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: There is no branch or tag with version 8.16.1 (anymore)

Comment: You can see the list of branches at https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases

Comment: Oops, sorry, https://github.com/laravel/laravel/releases. 8.16.1 is in laravel/framework, but laravel/laravel has 8.6.1 as the last of the current 8.x releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel doesn't have version `8.16.1`. Maybe you mean version `8.6.11`.

You can use :

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:8.6.11 blog
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem has been solved for laravel 8, but still appered when i create laravel 7 project using this command " composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 blog "

Comment: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "^7.0"`

Comment: Thank you for this. In my case I use PHP 8.1 and I was trying to create a laravel project using the 8 version but I was recieving the same question error, but with this command It works now. I just wanted to know why this works instead the laravel docs command suggested, thank you